# Split in nested from in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL query like this:

```
select ID,DepartmentID,Code from Department
where code in
(select SUBSTRING(Code, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Code)) from Department as d
inner join DepartmentPersonnel as dp on d.ID = dp.DepartmentID
inner join Personnel as p on dp.PersonneID = p.ID
where UserName='myUsername')
```

result this query is:

[image: myTable]

I tried to get this result in EF by this query:

```
var query = (from dd in db.Departments
             where (
                 from D in db.Departments
                 join DP in db.DepartmentPersonnels on D.ID equals DP.DepartmentID
                 join P in db.Personnels on DP.PersonneID equals P.ID
                 where P.UserName == Username
                 select D.Code.Split(',').First()).Contains(dd.Code)
             select dd).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I get this error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I read many posts to solve this issue but none have solved this problem.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `string.Split` method is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Fortunately, the SQL expression in question

```
SUBSTRING(Code, 0, CHARINDEX(',', Code))
```

has a direct LINQ equivalent using [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)(the overloads with `string` argument) which are supported.

So replace

```
D.Code.Split(',').First()
```

with

```
D.Code.Substring(0, D.Code.IndexOf(","))
```

But please note the translation of the above expression is not safe in case the target string does not contain "," inside. So you might need also to change the `where` clause to:

```
where P.UserName == Username && D.Code.IndexOf(",") >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks.I used query below `query=(from dd in db.Departments
                             join DP in db.DepartmentPersonnels on dd.ID equals DP.DepartmentID
                             join P in db.Personnels on DP.PersonneID equals P.ID
                 where P.UserName==Username
                 select dd).FirstOrDefault();
                string Code = query.Code.Split(',')[0];
                result=(from d in db.Departments
                          where d.Code==Code
                          select d).FirstOrDefault();`.Whether it is better in terms of performance?

Comment: Hmm, if the subquery is supposed to return single record, then this is viable solution. What about performance, you have to check that out (as people on SO say usually, run the horses :)