# LINQ query working fine in Dot Net Core 2.2 but in 3.1

Tags: linq, asp.net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

Below LINQ query working as expected in `Dot Net Core 2.2` but when I upgraded to `3.1` it throws runtime execption.

```
[HttpGet("{SINo}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> SaleHistory(string SINo)
{
    return await (from s in _context.Sales
                  where s.saleInvNo.Contains("|")
                        ? s.saleInvNo.Split("|", StringSplitOptions.None)[1] == SINo
                        : s.saleInvNo == SINo
                  select new
                  {
                      s.saleDate,
                      s.saleInvNo
                  }).ToListAsync();
}
```

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can
>   be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting
>   a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync()

How can I change this translatable query?

Note: Sales table has ~1 Million records. Out of it, I just want to get one record.

Comment: While it worked in EF Core 2.2, it would have given you a warning telling you this query would have been evaluated on the client and not in your database.

Comment: Also looking at this query, I strongly suggest you normalise this data to split out the "SINNo" value into its own column - there's no great way to query this style of data.

Comment: Assuming `saleInvNo` has 2 parts  based on `|` so how about if you try `s.saleInvNo.Substring(s.saleInvNo.IndexOf("|") + 1) == SINo` instead of `s.saleInvNo.Split("|", StringSplitOptions.None)[1] == SINo`?

Comment: @SelimYıldız Some times it may have only 1 part.

Comment: That is okay it should work for that too because you have already checked with `s.saleInvNo.Contains("|")`. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @SelimYıldız I just tried, your idea is working as expected. But any explanation for this please.

Comment: I have added an answer, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.Split` is not supported in LINQ to Entities. So that you need to use `Substring` and `IndexOf` together as follow.

Use:

```
s.saleInvNo.Substring(s.saleInvNo.IndexOf("|") + 1) == SINo
```

Instead of:

```
s.saleInvNo.Split("|", StringSplitOptions.None)[1] == SINo
```

See: [Split in nested from in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057009/split-in-nested-from-in-entity-framework)

By the way you should consider **@DavidG** suggestion:

> Also looking at this query, I strongly suggest you normalise this data
>   to split out the "SINNo" value into its own column - there's no great
>   way to query this style of data

Comment: While this will work, it still has problems. This will generate a query that is not "SARGable". This means the database will use an index scan or even a table scan. The only way to fix this issue and have a performant database is to have a column that contains the value you are searching for.

Comment: @DavidG you are right, agree. As you mentioned in comment section it would be better  if `normalise this data to split out the "SINNo" value into its own column`. I have updated my answer with adding your suggestion. Thanks for contribution.